# Import a list of words, dont wanna do it all over again in the code

Tags: python

I don't want to post too much code, but I have code for an assignment done, the problem with my code is that every time I run a method called `findchildren`, it imports my list every time. So I tried to change my code, and my `findchildren` is working, it's currently looking like this:

```
from queue import Queue

ordlista=[]
fil=open("labb9text.txt")
for line in fil.readlines():
    ordlista.append(line.strip())
setlista=set()
for a in ordlista:
    if a not in setlista:
        setlista.add(a)

def findchildren(lista,parent): 
    children=[]
    lparent=list(parent)
    lista.remove(parent)
    for word in lista:
        letters=list(word)
        count=0
        i=0
        for a in letters:
            if a==lparent[i]:
                count+=1
                i+=1
            else:
                i+=1
            if count==2:
                if word not in children:
                    children.append(word)
            if i>2:
                break
    return children
```

my problem is that I have another method, which worked when I didn't have the parameter `lista` in `findchildren` (instead I imported the list over and over, which I dont wanna do, I want to import it once, in the beginning). Notice that when I call my method, I call it with `labb9.findchildren(labb9.ordlista,"fan")`. So my `findchildren` is working currently, the problem is the method right under:

```
def way(start,end): 
    queue=Queue()
    queue.enqueue(start)
    visited=set()                       
    while not queue.isempty():
        vertex=queue.get()
        if vertex==end:
            return True
        else:
            visited.add(vertex)
            s=findchildren(labb999.ordlista,start)
            for vertex in s:
                if vertex not in visited:
                    queue.put(vertex)
                else:
                    visited.add(vertex)
    return False
```

Notice that the `way`-method used to work when I imported my list to `findchildren` every time, now that I've changed it to a parameter in `findchildren`, it does not work. I'm getting the error:

> name "lista" is not defined.

What am I doing wrong?

Comment: This is confusing.

Comment: Where does `labb999.ordlista` come from?

Comment: Can you post the full error stack trace please?

Comment: Just for simplicity, this part: `setlista=set()
for a in ordlista:
    if a not in setlista:
        setlista.add(a)` can be reduced to `setlista = set(ordlista)` (there are no doublons in sets.

Comment: We have no insight into what your code does or, more importantly, _is supposed to do_.

Comment: My code is BFS-code, the labb9text.txt is a text file with words containing three letters. For example fan, pol etc (mostly swedish words). My findchildren-method is supposed to find all words that is children to my "parent" word, lets say I choose "fan" as my word, then "man", "kan", "fab" is children to this word.

Comment: the labb999 is what my file is named, I cannot tell why I need to write the full labb999.ordlista, I simply have to write that when I call it, and that is probably why the line s=findchildren(labb999.ordlista,start is not working, but if I go with labb9.findchilren(labb999.ordlista,"fan") it's suddenly working, It's hard to describe what is wrong

Comment: maybe load the list of word in a global variable ? (I never know if global is a good idee or not)

Comment: The full error message is:
line 41, s=findchildren.....
line 13, lista.remove(par....
KeyError: 'fan'

Comment: Gonna try to simplify my problem, my findchildren is working when I call it in python as labb999.findchildren(labb999.setlista,"fan). It's printing exactly how I want, but the line in my way-method (s=findchildre....) is not working, I wonder, how do I fix that, where does it go wrong...

Comment: @JoakimDahl How do you define a parent? Words who first or last two letters are the same?

Comment: No, its only neccesary to have 2 letters in common, they dont have to be in order, for example, if parent is fan, fbn is children (fbn doesnt exist, but for example)

Answer (score 1):

Your goal is to find if there exists a path from `start` to `stop` where a path is described as words who have length two permutations overlapping.

I think your code would be better organized as a graph and a function that operates on this graph. It would eliminate all of your problems: you can have a single copy of your word set associated with your graph object and can operate directly on that object with your function `way`.

```
from queue import Queue
import itertools

class Graph(object):
    def __init__(self, filename):
        # Creates a set, which removes duplicates automatically
        self.word_set = {word for word in open(filename, 'r').read().split()}

    def _len_2_permutations(self, word):
        # Create a list of length two permutations from a word
        return itertools.permutations(word, 2)

    def has_word_overlap(self, word1, word2):
        # If there are any overlapping length two permutations, the set will not be empty
        return len(set(self._len_2_permutations(word1)) & set(self._len_2_permutations(word2))) > 0

    def find_children(self, start):
        # Children are those words who have overlapping length two perms
        return [word for word in self.word_set if self.has_word_overlap(start, word) and word != start]
```

Now we can define our BFS-like function:

```
def way(g, start, stop):
    queue = Queue()
    # Push start
    queue.put(start)
    visited = set()
    while not queue.empty():
        # Get the top of the queue
        vertex = queue.get()
        # If it's our target, we're done
        if vertex == stop:
            return True
        # Otherwise, visit it
        visited.add(vertex)
        # Find its children
        s = g.find_children(vertex)
        # Push the unvisited children -- explore them later
        for vertex in s:
            if vertex not in visited:
                queue.put(vertex)
    return False
```

Now let's create a main:

```
if __name__ == "__main__":
    g = Graph("foo.txt")
    start = "fan"
    stop = "foo"
    print("There's a path from '{0}' to '{1}': {2}".format(start, stop, way(g, start, stop)))
```

This code isn't thoroughly tested, but it should get you on the right track.

Comment: Thank you so much for your help Erip, I'm gonna have to test this by myself but finally I have something to work with, I'm probably gonna come back here for things I dont understand, I'm a newbie at programming so I gotta say that your first "graph" class is not looking like how I'm used to it!

Comment: @JoakimDahl Varsågod. If you have specific questions, feel free to ask. I've tested it a bit more and I think it works.